# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instance
Examples of this error:

> location: System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object instance, Attribute[] attributes)
>   konum: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateDesigner(IComponent component, Boolean rootDesigner)
>   location: System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo)
>   konum: System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
>   location: System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
>   location: System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>   location: System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>   location: System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
>   location: System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
>   location: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
>   location: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

The designers are not loading because of this error.

**Even if the designers do not install, the program is running.**

What should I do ?

Comment: May be any reference not passing or instantiate correctly

Comment: if you found your mistake you should delete this question. it's will not help anyone

Comment: @LeonBarkan No, i couldn't find

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim References are all working correctly

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim All the designers give the same error but the program works. It is not clear where the error is. And does not appear in the error list. When I open the designer, it gives this error.